# WPF: Expander.Header - dock control right

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander

I want the red button in the expander header to be docked right. How can I do this?
[image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="spTest" Margin="10">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Expander Margin="5,0,5,0">
            <Expander.Header>
                <Grid Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="TEXT1 1231521312"  Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Text2"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Grid.Column="2" Width="40" Height="40" Background="#F8CECC" Content="X" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="18" BorderBrush="#B95753"/>
                </Grid>
            </Expander.Header>
        </Expander>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from `ContentPresenter` used for header in default template. `ContentPresenter` has it's `HorizontalAlignment` set not to the `Stretch`. To change it you could try to bind `HorizontalAlignment` of the `Grid` to the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `ContentPresenter`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="spTest" Margin="10">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Expander Margin="5,0,5,0">
            <Expander.Header>
                <Grid Margin="5,0,0,0" 

                    HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, Mode=OneWayToSource}">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="TEXT1 1231521312"  Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Text2"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Grid.Column="2" Width="40" Height="40" Background="#F8CECC" Content="X" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="18" BorderBrush="#B95753"/>
                </Grid>
            </Expander.Header>
        </Expander>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Another way, which would work with nested `Expander` is to set/bind the `Grid.Width`.

```
<Grid Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}, Converter={StaticResource SubtractConverter}, ConverterParameter=5}">

public class SubtractConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 
            (double)value 
            - 20/*Default template: Grid's column width */ 
            - 4/*Default template: margin of ContentPresenter*/ 
            - 2/*Default template:  2*BorderThikness */ 
            - double.Parse(parameter as string) /*Margin of Grid in Header*/;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Another way would be override default template for `Expander` see [Expander Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/expander-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Now I have the problem, that a nested expander will not act the same :-(

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxNNL.png